# How to adjust SPF record to a second SMTP server?

Tags: email, mail-server, spf

My current SPF record for the email provider was configured as such:

```
v=spf1 a mx ptr include:bluehost.com ?all
```

I signed up for a service to send out some of my emails via their SMTP servers and they recommend using the following SPF config:

```
v=spf1 a mx include:authsmtp.com ~all
```

My dilemma is combining the two? (I still have some email accounts that will need to use the old mail server).

Answer (score 0):

The first entry does basically nothing because the `?all` stands for NEUTRAL. What you are probably after is a SOFTFAIL = `~all`

```
v=spf1 a mx ptr include:bluehost.com include:authsmtp.com ~all
```

Make sure to check that your SPF record doesn't need too many DNS lookups. You can check your host here: http://spf.myisp.ch